# In pandas, filter for duplicate values appearing in 1 of 2 different columns, for list of certain values only

Tags: python, pandas

```
zed = pd.DataFrame(data = { 'date': ['2022-03-01', '2022-03-02', '2022-03-03', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-05'], 'a': [1, 5, 7, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 4, 9, 12, 5] })
```

How can the following dataframe be filtered to keep the earliest row (earliest == lowest date) for each of the 3 values `1, 5, 4` appearing in either column `a` or column `b`? In this example, the rows with dates `'2022-03-01'`, `'2022-03-02'` would be kept as they are the lowest dates where each of the 3 values appears?

We have tried `zed[zed.isin({'a': [1, 5, 4], 'b': [1, 5, 4]}).any(1)].sort_values(by=['date'])` but this returns the incorrect result as it returns 3 rows.

Comment: 1, 5, 4 in any order or not?

Comment: Reshape your dataframe `zed.set_index('date').stack()`, it will be easier. What is the expected output?

Comment: kept based on the `date` column, ascending. since 1, 5, and 4 collectively appear in the first 2 dates `2022-03-01` and `2022-03-02`, these should be the only 2 rows kept

Comment: Our full dataframe has many other columns that make reshaping the dataframe a bit more difficult. For this example dataframe using `.stack()` may be easier, but for our full dataframe, an approach that does not reshape the dataframe would be preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), so possible filterin gby list with remove duplicates:

```
s = zed.set_index('date')[['a','b']].stack()
idx = s[s.isin([1, 5, 4])].drop_duplicates().index.remove_unused_levels().levels[0]

print (idx)
Index(['2022-03-01', '2022-03-02'], dtype='object', name='date')

out = zed[zed['date'].isin(idx)]
print (out)
         date  a  b
0  2022-03-01  1  3
1  2022-03-02  5  4
```

Or filter first index value matching conditions, get unique values and select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
L = [1, 5, 4]
idx = pd.unique([y for x in L for y in zed[zed[['a', 'b']].eq(x).any(axis=1)].index[:1]])

df = zed.loc[idx]
print (df)
         date  a  b
0  2022-03-01  1  3
1  2022-03-02  5  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Without reshape your dataframe, you can use:

```
idx = max([zed[['a', 'b']].eq(i).sum(axis=1).idxmax() for i in [1, 5, 4]])
out = zed.loc[:idx]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
         date  a  b
0  2022-03-01  1  3
1  2022-03-02  5  4
```